# Why does SO log me in with a wrong account?

Tags: support, openid, login, google-openid

I have 2 google accounts call them A and B. When I'm logged into google with A and try to login to SO with B it logs me in with A.

To clarify when SO asks me for my "openid" I type in my full email address.

Is it a bug or am I not understanding some open id ideas?

Comment: I think this question belongs here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: +1 but migrate to Meta. (@audio.zoom: don't touch the question, it will be migrated for you!)

Comment: btw while trying to add both of my google open ids having 2 so windows open i actually managed to get an error message.

Comment: "To clarify when SO asks me for my 'openid' I type in my full email address." You don't just click on the big Google button?

Comment: thats right - i type in my email address and hit enter

Comment: @Richard it is the answer i expected, but then the whole manual process confused me. What is it that I'm supposed to type in there?

Comment: @audio.zoom - Don't bother ;) just hit the big Google button, but if you really want to know you'd type `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`

Comment: wow so it is a "weird" problem! It definitely works the same as hitting the big google button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not understanding part of OpenID.

If you're "logged into Google with A" any sites you visit using a Google OpenID will log you in using A.

OpenID is a kind of Single Sign On concept, where you log in once (to Google, as A) and reuse that login session (glossary help there anyone?) on multiple sites.

I have no idea how or why it works when you input your Gmail address as your OpenID URL. My instincts would have told me that that would give an error message... but it does seem to work.

This should be brought to the attention of one of the higher ups; I can't say if it's a SO problem or a "Google's OpenID implementation, which is kind of weird" problem.